# Show that $x/e^x<1.5/x^2$ for $x>0$

Tags: inequality, lambert-w

I have trouble with proving the following inequality

$$\frac{x}{e^x}<\frac{1.5}{x^2}$$ for $x>0$.

My attempt:
$$1.5e^x-x^3>0$$
Let $f(x)=1.5e^x-x^3$
$$f'(x)=1.5e^x-3x^2 $$
$$f'(x)=0$$
$$e^x=2x^2$$
Using the Lambert $W$-function I get three solutions:
$$x=-0.539835, x=1.48796,x=2.61787$$
Drawing the graph of $f'(x)$ I can see that the derivative is not always greater than $0$ for $x>0$, so I cannot say the function monotonically increases.

Is there a simpler way to prove this? Maybe using the Lambert $W$-function is not necessary at all?

Comment: Observe that the derivative is negative from $x=1.48796$ to $x=2.61787$, but $f(x)$ is still positive at $x=2.61787$. After $x=2.61787$, the derivative is always positive, hence $f(x)$ is always positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $x^2$ is positive, proving this inequality is equivalent to proving that

$$\frac{x^3}{e^x} < 1.5$$

Let's call $f(x) = x^3/e^x$. Then

$$f'(x) = \frac{3x^2}{e^x} - \frac{x^3}{e^x} = \frac{(3-x)x^2}{e^x}$$

Note that for $x>0$, $f'(x)$ has a unique root, $x=3$. For $0<x<3$, $f'(x)>0$, and for $x>3$, $f'(x)<0$. Thus, $f(x)$ has a unique global maximum at $x=3$. For all $x>0$, $f(x) \le f(3)$.

$$f(3) = \frac{27}{e^3} \approx 1.34425 < 1.5$$

Thus, the inequality is true.